# How can I convert a Phaser 3 game into an android game?

Tags: javascript, npm, apk, phaser-framework

I'm fairly new to Phaser and I would like to know if there is any way by means of which I can convert the Phaser game into android game.

I'm using Phaser with NPM.

thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are a few boilerplates floating around, which I haven't personally tested, making use of Cordova for the goal you're aiming at:

- https://github.com/PeeJeeDR/phaser-3-webpack-cordova
- https://github.com/ReydVires/phaser3-cordova

As far as more official resources if you were so inclined:

- An e-book: [HTML5 CROSS PLATFORM GAMES USING PHASER 3](https://phaser.io/shop/books/phaser3-cross-platform-games)
- A 2018 tutorial: https://phaser.io/news/2018/04/capacitor-and-phaser-tutorial
- A June 2021 [OpenForge Ionic video from the official blog aswell](https://phaser.io/news/2021/06/openforge-ionic-video) and [related repository](https://github.com/openforge/openfarm-ionic-angular-phaser-example)

I'll go ahead and suggest this blog article aswell which seem pretty well made to me, using Capacitor: [Create HTML5 Native games in Ionic Capacitor apps using Phaser](https://enappd.com/blog/html5-games-in-ionic-capacitor-using-phaser/115/)
 with the [related repository.](https://github.com/enappd/Ionic4-phaser)